# svn command line not working from Python

Tags: svn

I run following svn command successfully on cmd.exe(Win 7):

```
svn info "svn://azsvn/..some path"
```

however, running the following through Python as:

```
path = 'svn://azsvn/..some path'
cmd_str = 'svn info ' + path
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_string, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

returns empty.
What I am doing wrong?

sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set stdout and stderr to PIPE, like this:

```
   proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_string, shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
```

In this way the communicate() method will return the expected tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that when you are running the command from the shell, the shell is stripping off the quotes on "pth" and passing in the shell-processed command

```
 svn info pth
```

But when you are using the API library, they are attempting to honor the command as closely as possible to the parameters you pass into the library, so when it gets executed it runs something like

```
 svn info "pth"
```

In the actual SVN processor.  This likely has the issue of SVN not knowing a file like `"pth"` and failing.

I'd try a cmd_str of `svn info pth` an see if I achieved the desired results.  In addition, you might find that running a command in the shell of `svn info \"pth\"` might fail in a manner similar to your Python launch.

Comment: Actually, when I run the above in Pycharm4.5.3, I can see command return the information expected in console window but the _out_ and _err_ variables read _None_ value

Comment: Quotes and shells can be tricky.  Basically you have to concede that many shells process strings before executing them, and that processing is very dependent on the positions of quotes (if they are there).  APIs on the other hand, don't do what shells do, because well, they are not shells.

Comment: I have updated my question,sorry about less information before